# Delete Object from Array and destroy it completely

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of Objects (ES6 Class I created). When I delete this objects from within the array I store them, it seems like it isnt fully "destroyed". These Object classes have websocket connections to external APIs and even when I remove these Objects from my Object Array using splice (which works) I still see the websocket events coming in for them.

How can I really destroy the whole Instance of the object when I remove it from my array?

Comment: Is there a disconnect type method on the object?

Comment: Yes. But how can it still make use of the websocket functionalitx within that class when I have set it to null. I dont understand it.

Comment: You probably need to explicitly close the connection, not just discard the connection object.

Comment: Even if it's closed by the garbage collector, GC doesn't happen immediately.

Comment: when I use the websocket.close() function inside that Object, it stops logging, I am not sure tho if the Object will really get destroyed afterwards tho

Comment: Adding your code might be useful. If there are no more references to that object instance after you set it null it should be deleted by GC.

Comment: You need to do both: websocket.close() *and* remove it from the array.